# How to change the look of a textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to have a multiline textbox of max of 3 rows and I also want to modify it`s width and height size.  How can I do that in mvc?

The following code is not working

```
 @Html.TextBox("myTextBox", String.Empty, new { @style = "width: 150px; ,height : 80px; multiline = true", @MAXLENGTH = "2000" })
```

Comment: Are you wanting to do this at runtime? Where in your code have you placed this line?

Comment: Also, remove the extra comma (before _height_) in the style you've defined.

Comment: I have removed the comma, but it still though it is of a certian height, I don`t have it as multiline

Comment: @learning because you cannot make text input a multiline one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A html-textbox is always single-line. Use a TextArea instead:

```
@Html.TextArea("myTextArea", String.Empty, 10, 40, new { style=""})
```

You can alter the 10 (rows) and 40 (columns) for another width/height, or set it directly with width and height in the style.

Comment: like tugberk said, no, it can't. You're probably refering to a WebForm-TextBox. That one has a property called Multiline, but see in the source-code of your HTML what WebForms generates there: a textarea!

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.TextArea("Foo", new { row = 3, style = "width:300px;height:30px;" })
```

**Edit:**

First of all, there is nothing called textbox on html spec. ASP.NET MVC ain't Web Forms. It is `input` element whose `type` attribute is set to `text`.

Second, show me how you do it. The multiline version of a text input is `textarea`.

Comment: I don`t want  textarea rather a texbox which is multiline

Comment: @learning first of all, there is nothing called **textbox** on html spec. ASP.NET MVC ain't web forms. it is `input` element whose `type` attribute is set to `text`. Second, show me how you do it. The multiline version of a text input is textarea.